# Angular2 how to bind map object from @input

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I have input in HTML like this:

```
<input class="form-control"
                   maxlength="255"
                   placeholder=""
                   type="text"
                   [(ngModel)]="data.translations[item.key]"
                   name="translations[{{item.key}}]"
                   >
```

I get from server DTO which contains map obejct. The DTO has name **data** and map name is **translations**.

Problem is, that for first time is value set to input correctly. But after button click, which sends value of input to server is input reset. I need the value to stay in input box. I think, that this binding should work. But it isn't.

Please help me, how I could correct this issue.

Comment: There is no button in the code in your question. What does a button click do?

Comment: the `data .translations` would have changed if you want it to remain the same add it to a local component varaible and set that to the `data.translations[item.key]` and send the local variable to the server and

Comment: I am sorry. Button sends **data** to server, then reloads this data. I release that problem is in this line: 'this.form.reset(value);' 
Which is executed after button click. The value is map and it isn't sets values by their keys.

Comment: Are you achieved this?

Comment: @SureshB did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

My colleague fix this with attributte: [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
So now it looks like:

```
<input class="form-control" 
       maxlength="255" 
       placeholder="" 
       type="text" 
       [(ngModel)]="data.translations[item.key]" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
       name="translations[{{item.key}}]" >
```